# Problem printing scatter plots: x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot two scatter plots in different graphs but inside the same figure. I am using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 10))
ax[0].scatter(city_join.pop, city_join.log_lights1992)
ax[1].scatter(city_join.pop, city_join.log_lights2013)
```

where city_join is a shapefile and pop, log_lights1992 and log_lights2013 are the columns I would like to use.

When I use that code the following error appears: "x and y must be the same size". Looking online, for example, here [ValueError: x and y must be the same size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659535/valueerror-x-and-y-must-be-the-same-size) , and here [matplotlib error: x and y must be the same size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55415891/matplotlib-error-x-and-y-must-be-the-same-size) , they say that the problem could be that the variables/columns have a different shape of size.

However, when I do what they suggested it seems that my columns have the same size (shape).

[image]

I really do not understand what's going on. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe log_lights2013 has a wrong shape

Comment: Thank you for your comment @dangom. It has the same shape than log_lights1992

Comment: I assume matplotlib is getting confused due to the name of your column being pop, and the function [`df.pop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html). Try `ax[0].scatter(city_join["pop"], city_join["og_lights1992"])`

Comment: Thank you @DavidG . When I do that, it gives me a new error: " KeyError: 'pop' "