# ValueError: x and y must be the same size when drawing ax[i].scatter in plt.subplots()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot the **tradeMoney** of every day in `scatter()`.
So I just write a simple one as fllows:

```
plt.scatter(train_EDA[(train_EDA['tradeMonth'] == 1)]['tradeDay'],\
            train_EDA[(train_EDA['tradeMonth'] == 1)]['tradeMoney'])
```

[image]

It is definitely right.
So I try to plot every month as follows:

```
nrows, ncols = 12, 1
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=12, ncols=1, figsize=(8, 96))

for i in range(12):
    ax[i].scatter(train_EDA[(train_EDA['tradeMonth'] == i)]['tradeDay'], 
train_EDA[(train_EDA['tradeMonth'] == 1)]['tradeMoney'])
```

The plots are all blank.
And error messages are as fllows:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         3 
>         4 for i in range(12):
>   ----> 5     ax[i].scatter(train_EDA[(train_EDA['tradeMonth'] == i)]
> ['tradeDay'], train_EDA[(train_EDA['tradeMonth'] ==
>   1)]['tradeMoney'])
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py in inner(ax,
>   data, *args, **kwargs)    
> 1808                         "the Matplotlib
>   list!)" % (label_namer, func.**name**),    
> 1809
>   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
>   
> -> 1810             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)    
> 1811     
> 1812         inner.**doc** = _add_data_doc(inner.**doc**,
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py in
>   scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha,
>   linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)    
> 4180         y =
>   np.ma.ravel(y)    
> 4181         if x.size != y.size:
>   
> -> 4182             raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")    
> 4183     
> 4184         if s is None:
>
> ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Here is the dataframe:

```
    tradeMonth  tradeDay    tradeMoney
0   12          22          16000.0
1   11          14          14000.0
2   2           10          6000.0
3   4           16          3400.0
4   2           28          8000.0
5   3           24          3000.0
......
......
......
```

After searching for [some relevant questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659535/valueerror-x-and-y-must-be-the-same-size), its error is mostly caused by the dimensions of data.
BUT there is no such problem. 
Could anyone help me how to solve it?

Comment: Can you put the data frame?

Comment: Also, I suggest you put a color for every month.

Comment: @KenrySanchez Thanks for your comments and tips about putting a different color for every month. I would like to use a `list` to save **12 colors** for **12 months** and use it in the corresponding plot. Sir do you think it is a wise strategy? And shame on me for this mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you accidentally left a `1` where you wanted an `i`; change

```py
ax[i].scatter(train_EDA[(train_EDA['tradeMonth'] == i)]['tradeDay'], 
train_EDA[(train_EDA['tradeMonth'] == 1)]['tradeMoney'])
```

to

```py
ax[i].scatter(train_EDA[(train_EDA['tradeMonth'] == i)]['tradeDay'], 
train_EDA[(train_EDA['tradeMonth'] == i)]['tradeMoney'])
```

Comment: Still, I don't believe this solve the problem. It's just he is always choosing the same trade month